# How to export state variable from PEG.js parser

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing, peg, pegjs

I'm starting to use excellent [PEG.JS](https://pegjs.org/online) JavaScript parser generator 
to implement Qt's `qmake` project file parser (*.pro). 
It looks bash script, with variable assignments and function calls.
First of all, i need to parse all assignments to some kind of `Dictionary`,
and use it in external code.

I can't undestand how to access internal parser state from the external function.
I.e.: i need to parse my `pro`-file, and save state into client code-accessible variable, e.g. JavaScript Dictionary.
But i can't achieve this!

Grammar (right now understood only assignment statement like `TEMPLATE = app`):

```
{
    var SystemVariablesDict = {};
}

Start = Statement*
Statement = Whitespace GenericAssignmentStatement Whitespace
GenericAssignmentStatement = TemplateAssignmentStatement

// TEMPLATE = app|lib|subdirs|aux|vcapp|vclib
SystemTemplateVariableName = "TEMPLATE"
SystemTemplateVariableValue = "app" / "lib" / "subdirs" / "aux" / "vcapp" / "vclib"
TemplateAssignmentStatement = lvalue:SystemTemplateVariableName 
AssignmentOperator rvalue:SystemTemplateVariableValue
{
    // [REF 1] !!! Assignment to the global state variable !!!
    SystemVariablesDict[lvalue] = rvalue;
    return undefined;
}

AssignmentOperator = Whitespace "=" Whitespace

Word = w:Character+ { return w.join(""); }
Character = c:[a-zA-Z0-9]
Whitespace = [ \t\r\n]*
```

(The grammar above was successfully compiled in the `qmake-project-parser.js`)
The parser usage code (`frontend.js` file):

```
var pegjs = require("./qmake-project-parser.js");
var parserOutput = pegjs.parse("TEMPLATE = app");
console.log("PEG.js parser output:");
console.log(parserOutput);
console.log("System variables dict:");
console.log(pegjs.SystemVariablesDict);
```

And the output:

```
C:\Projects\qmake-project-parser>node frontend.js
PEG.js parser output:
[ [ [], undefined, [] ] ]
System variables dict:
**undefined**
```

The question is: why **undefined** was outputed, however the **REF 1** rule was successfully applied?
What am i doing wrong?

Thanks!

P.S. I'm new to JavaScript, so be patient to my silly mistakes please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I remember from using PEG.js, the start rule is generally used to return whatever you want to return as parser output:

```
Start = Statement* { return SystemVariablesDict }
```

Which should end up in `parserOutput`.

Comment: Thanks! now parser itself returns desired `Dictionary`. But using this way i can use only one global state variable. Is there a way to "forward" client code variables to PEG.js internals?

Comment: You can of course export a nested object that holds everything that you want to pass from the parser to the calling code.

Comment: Ok, accepted! I need to learn type system in JavaScript deeper